# circular movement: simple math algorithm

Tags: flash, math

I have to calculate dx and dy so player1 has a circular movement.

[image]

I thin it is cos and sin related !
regards

Comment: Do you an angle between the current point and the next point to be moved to ?

Comment: Do you have a centerpoint? With two points there are an infinite number of circles that have both points on their edge (asll are centered on a line that is equidistant from the two points. You will need to have more information for a unique answer which could be something like the angle that the arc should make, the radius of the circle you want (the minimum allowed radius being half the distance between the points), a tangent to the arc at some point (likely to be the start or end point), another point that you want it to go through, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework. Here are some basic elements to get you *started*:

```
var angle:Number = 45;
var centerPoint:Point = new Point(100,100);
var radius:uint = 100;
var radian:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
var x:Number = (centerPoint.x + radius) * Math.cos(radian);
var y:Number = (centerPoint.y + radius) * Math.sin(radian);
```

In this case, you would need to work the x and y variables into a function that gets called over time, where the angle variable increments towards an endpoint (your target).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well,

x=h+cos(angle) and
y=k+sin(angle)

where h is the x-coordinate of the center and k is the y-coordinate of the center.

So if you want to know what dx and dy are, then just take the derivative of both of those equations with respect to t (d/dt).